# Recursively printing a diamond with a single argument

Tags: c++, recursion

The following code does what I want, but I need it such that the triangle function takes only a single parameter, the maxrow. I think it is probably necessary for the function to countdown from the maxrow until it is equal to 1, but how to initiate printing from the middle of the diamond perplexes me. How can this be possible?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
void print_row(unsigned int cnt)
{
     while(cnt --> 0) std::cout << "* "; // or for loop, I just think --> is cute
     std::cout << '\n';
}

void triangle(int maxrow, int row = 0)
{
     if (row >= maxrow)
     {
         print_row(row);
     }
     else
     {
         std::cout << std::string(maxrow-row, ' ');
         print_row(row);

         triangle(maxrow, row+1);

         std::cout << std::string(maxrow-row, ' ');
         print_row(row);
     }
}

int main()
{
     std::cout << "Enter total lines: ";
     int x;
     std::cin >> x;
     std::cout << '\n';
     triangle(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper function and call it:

```
void triangle_helper(int maxrow) {
    triangle(maxrow, 0);
}
```

You can further rename `triangle_helper` to `triangle`, and `triangle` to `triangle_impl` for example, and/or put it in some private namespace.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae8427c8cf40cbef)